# using the uint package with OCaml - opam

Tags: ocaml, uint64, opam

I just installed [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/) and installed the uint package. However when I attempt to do something like this

```
File : Hello.ml
let ash(mystring) = (
    let basis =   uint64.of_string("0xcbf29ce484221325") in
    Printf.printf "Function Finished" ;
);;

ash("Hello");;
```

I get the error

```
Error: Unbound value uint64
```

Any suggestions on what I could be missing ? I am new to OCaml and opam

I used the following statement to compile the code in my OSX terminal

```
ocaml Hello.ml
```

Comment: Is this in the top level, is it compiled, what flags did you use, how did you compile it? You got to give us more than just it doesn't work.

Comment: Ill add my entire code here. Sorry I was not aware of those details

Comment: You forgot to capitalize uint64 in Uint64.of_string. Modules are always capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues, you don't need the () around arguments unless you intend them to be a tuple of values (Perhaps a topic you'll learn later down the road)

Plain `ocaml` is just like an interpreter, it doesn't know where installed code is (Perhaps you're used to like python where the interpreter has a few places that it looks on its own first)

```
let ash mystring =
  let basis = Uint64.of_string "0xcbf29ce484221325" in
  Printf.printf "Function Finished"

let () =
  ash "Hello"
```

Assuming that is called hello.ml, you can compile it with

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package uint -linkpkg hello.ml -o Test
```

(This is using the `ocamfind` wrapper and it calls `ocamlc` for you and tells it to use the uint package and link it for the final executable called `Test`)

and then run it with

```
./Test
```

Comment: @JamesFranco `opam install ocamlfind`

Comment: It says.` [NOTE] Package ocamlfind is already installed (current version is 1.5.5)` . I am a little confused as to why it cant find it. Do I need to set it up in the environment variables ?

Comment: Open new shell/terminal, do `eval \`opam config env\`` Then check if ocamlfind is present, `which ocamlfind`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick - looks like I needed to do  `eval \`opam config env\``

Comment: @JamesFranco No problem, if you're curious later you can read this answer that delves a little deeper in OCaml toolchain, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543465/function-applied-to-too-many-arguments-in-lablgtk/30606309#30606309